# Associations not working properly in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have the following Models

```
Shop
_____________________________________
Id  Name  address  city postalcode ...


Category
_______________________________________
Id  Name  Description  shop_id  ...

Product
______________________________________
Id Name Description category_id  ...
```

And my `Product` Model I have defined `$belongsTo` relation like

```
public $belongsTo = array(
            'Category' => array(
                'className' => 'Category',
                'conditions' => array('Category.shop_id' => 5)
            )
        );
```

What I need is that when I want to add New Product, in the Categories SelectBox should appear only Categories belonging to `shop_id = 5` but I am getting all Categories.

Or i have to change the find method?

Comment: Have you tried clearing your model caches?

Comment: where may i find these caches?

Comment: **/app/tmp/cache/model/**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need to add the conditions in the find query as you require it for add product
form.

Comment: To clear cache in cakephp, simply turn on and off the debug level in your config/core.php file